# Executar funcao após 3 segundos Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código, que crio duas variaveis e chamo uma funcao que exibe um alert, porém quero que a funcao verifica_abertura() seja executa após 3 segundos, como fazer isso?

```
var valor_min = 20;
var valor_max = 40;
verifica_abertura(valor_min, valor_max);

function verifica_abertura(valor_min, valor_max){
    alert(valor_min);
    alert(valor_max);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Circunde com

```
setTimeout(function(){ /*código a ser executado no tempo informado*/ }, 3000);
```

o parâmetro 3000 é o tempo em milisegundos

```js
var valor_min = 20;
var valor_max = 40;
setTimeout(function(){
  verifica_abertura(valor_min, valor_max);
}, 3000);

function verifica_abertura(valor_min, valor_max){
    alert(valor_min);
    alert(valor_max);
}
```